# Unity diffuse curve world shader

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to make a my objects to appear curved like Subway game, so I use this shader, it's working Editor, but doesn't produce any thing on Android device

I try to make a my objects to appear curved like Subway game, so I use this shader, it's working Editor, but doesn't produce any thing on Android device

```
Shader "Custom/CurvedWorld"
{
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 150

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert noforwardadd  vertex:vert

sampler2D _MainTex;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}

void vert( inout appdata_full v)
{
    float4 _QOffset= float4(-5,-5,0,0);
    float _Dist=100.0;
    vv.xyz -= _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz;
    float4 vPos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex);
    float zOff = vPos.z/_Dist;
    vPos += _QOffset*zOff*zOff;
    v.vertex = mul (vPos, UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV);
    v.texcoord = mul( UNITY_MATRIX_TEXTURE0, v.texcoord );    
}
ENDCG
}


}
```